# Why is only the first Child Process printing something out?

Tags: c++, fork, child-process

The program I am working on is called myfile - It should find a file in a certain searchpath. You should also be able to search for multiple files and if so, I **MUST** create multiple child processes with **fork()**. The problem is, i dont get the expected outcome printed out. If I am searching for multiple files, only the first file gets "returned". I think it has something todo with the second for in the else statement. For debugging I am printing out every PID of the child processes. Is the problem maybe that the child processes are working with the same variables at the same time?

**The Code:**
`

```
#include<iostream>
#include<dirent.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    struct dirent *d;
    DIR *dr;
    dr = opendir(argv[1]);

    pid_t pid;
    int numberOfFiles = argc - 2;
    if(dr!=NULL){
        if(numberOfFiles == 1){
            // normal search without fork
            for(d=readdir(dr); d!=NULL; d=readdir(dr)){
                if(strcmp(d->d_name, argv[argc-1]) == 0){
                    cout << "<" << getpid() << ">: " << argv[argc-1] << ": <" << realpath(argv[argc-1], NULL) << ">" <<endl;
                }
            }
        }else{
            // search with fork
            for(int i = 2; i < argc; i++){
                if(fork() == 0){
                    cout << "Current PID: " << getpid() << " " << argv[i] <<endl;
                    for(d=readdir(dr); d!=NULL; d=readdir(dr)){
                        if(strcmp(d->d_name, argv[i]) == 0){
                            cout << "Current i=" << i << " "<< "<" << getpid() << ">: " << argv[i] << ": <" << realpath(argv[i], NULL) << ">" <<endl;
                        }
                    }
                    exit(0);
                }
            }
            for(int i=0; i < numberOfFiles; i++){
                wait(NULL);
            }
        }
    }else
        cout<<"\nError Occurred!"<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`
**Screenshot of output in terminal:**
[image]

The problem is, i dont get the expected outcome printed out. If I am searching for multiple files, only the first file gets "returned". I think it has something todo with the second for in the else statement. For debugging I am printing out every PID of the child processes. Is the problem maybe that the child processes are working with the same variables at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a problem with `opendir`, `readdir`, and reusing variables. I cut your program down to:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct dirent *d;
    DIR *dr;
    dr = opendir(argv[1]);

    for (int i = 2; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if (fork() == 0)
        {
            cout << "Current PID: " << getpid() << " " << argv[i] << endl;
            for (d = readdir(dr); d != NULL; d = readdir(dr))
            {
                cout << getpid() << "\t" << d->d_name << endl;
            }
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < argc - 2; i++)
        wait(NULL);
}
```

And got this output (from `./testfork ../bla 1 2`):

```
Current PID: 17197 1
Current PID: 17198 2
17198   test.txt
17198   ..
17198   .
```

Which shows that once one process has read to end with `readdir`, then the other gets nothing. However, if I move the call to `opendir` to after the `fork`:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct dirent *d;
    DIR *dr;

    for (int i = 2; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if (fork() == 0)
        {
            dr = opendir(argv[1]);  // <- Here
            cout << "Current PID: " << getpid() << " " << argv[i] << endl;
            for (d = readdir(dr); d != NULL; d = readdir(dr))
            {
                cout << getpid() << "\t" << d->d_name << endl;
            }
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < argc - 2; i++)
        wait(NULL);
}
```

The the output becomes:

```
Current PID: 17751 1
17751   test.txt
17751   ..
17751   .
Current PID: 17752 2
17752   test.txt
17752   ..
17752   .
```

I don't quite understand why this happens, since the way `fork` works should ensure that each process get their own copy of the memory (though possibly only after writing to it). So when one process modifies `dr`, then that change should not be reflected in the other processes.

Perhaps it is due to `dr` actually being changed through system calls (by way of `readdir`), and not by the process directly?